# Стиль или класс в css

Tags: css

У меня есть таблица, для двух th необходимо задать **`text-align: left`** для других двух **`text-align:right`**. Раньше был выделенный класс для этого дела, который содержал одно свойство text-align. При пересмотре кода, задумался, а не лучше ли это записать в стиль?:

```
<th style="text-align: left">
```

Comment: Я приверженец полного разделения, поэтому я бы оставил класс, пусть даже всего с одним правилом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое негласное правило: если код нужно написать 2 раза - то нужно писать функцию. Здесь ситуация аналогичная.

Comment: @dimka3210, Тут и одного раза достаточно ;) Например, для body, какой-нибудь общей обертки etc., пишем мы один раз, но мало кто сегодня будет это делать в атрибуте style